# kernel - Executing in Ring0 -> risks?

Tags: security, unix, kernel, privileges, virtual-address-space

This question is **very** (and only) theoretical.

Please consider this situation :

- Running in ring0 <-> maximum privilege.
- If one has a kernel with, say, 20 trusted running processes.
- Each process reads/writes/execs from its own page, and cannot do otherwise <-> segfault
- Those processes have a virtual addresses very far apart from each others, which should provide enough process isolation.
- They are set by a manager (root) and run themselves with the least privileges (ldt bits set appropriately)
- Only trusted coders add the carefully reviewed code -> trust.

---

Are there still some risks to blow the whole system up regarding segfaults ?

**Is that isolation strategy enough if users are trusted ?**

---

## Update *(to answer ninjalj)* :

1) The processes don't need to communicate with each others. If in the future they need to, they will thanks to a large ring buffer with predetermined offsets and atomic locks and full RCu support (already done in prediction).

If ever the buffer gets full (should not happen because there are a lot of extreme tests done to set the values at a proper size), they will wait before adding anything (to resync, but that is the very very worst case).

2) No interprocess validation required. They all act as if they were alone on the machine.

3) We have full RCU support (even if not needed by processes right now, but will soon be). Where not practicable, basic atomic locks.

4) DMA is placed at a physical offset which should never be rewritable (large offset). It is currently put in the low physical memory. Guard pages protect this zone.

Comment: How do these kernel processes communicate with each other? Do they properly validate requests from other processes? Can a process rewrite a request it has already sent to another process (it is on shared memory)? Do you have DMA-capable devices? Can these devices overwrite your memory?

Comment: @ninjalj: Nice points, let me update my question ;)